# Difference between different binary formats

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

What are the difference between binary formats like COFF, ELF, a.out, etc, why do so many different formats exist?

All they have to be is a sequence of instructions and their arguments (specified by the ISA). So as long as the processor is the same, you can use the same binary between computers (currently needs to be of compatible ABI).

Comment: Did you do any research at all before posting this question?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, but none explained the necessity of so many formats.

Comment: "Why do they exist?" - same reason there's more than one programming language, more than one operating system, or more than one compiler.

Comment: Notice that the first MS-DOS binaries (.com files) *were* just a sequence of instructions and their arguments, specified by the ISA. You might want to research what features the next format (.exe files, in the "MS-DOS MZ format") offered.

Comment: Please explain to me how you would implement shared libraries, imports, exports with a raw blob of machine code.  Please elaborate on how the OS would know to mark code as executable, and some data regions as read-only, with a raw blob of machine code.  Please define ABI, when all you have is a blob of machine code.

Comment: ...and how to encode debugging symbols, how to indentify what processor settings are expected (like big endian/little endian for ARM), what version of the OS is expected for system calls, ...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart To call functions a shared library, load the library onto memory and jump to appropriate address. Code is marked executable by the filesystem. The program flow should be such that there is no way data regions are executed.

Comment: @LandonDonovan What is *"appropriate address"* if all you have is a blob of code?  *"marked executable by the filesystem"* how? Again, it's just a blob of code that the loader plopped into memory (according to you).  *"program flow should be such that there is no way data regions are executed."* - Sure, programs should never have bugs, I agree. But the unfortunate reality is this is not always the case. The system is responsible for utilizing the features of virtual memory to protect against this, which is simply not possible **without structured binary formats**.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: History and development. See the [feature comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats) at Wikipedia.

Better answer: Your assumptions are wrong. It is definitely not just code and initialized variables; much wider range of features are needed. There is no universal executable format, or a best executable format, as the features needed vary in different cases. Usually, we also want to keep backwards support; and why switch from a known working solution to a new one, if you don't have to? Because the new one is "universal" is just silly (actually stupid, if you consider how badly monocultures fare in the real, changing world).

Currently, [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format is the closest we have to an "universal" format, and is used by many current operating systems -- although both Windows and Mac OS use their own formats for basically historical reasons. (Windows retains backwards portability, later having switching to a COFF-based "portable executable" format, COFF itself not being that portable; Mac OS X uses Mach-O format, which is directly related to its kernel.)